# Close bootstrap modal if the button is not placed inside modal-body

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

So, I have this modal I'm using for a full screen menu and the close button is working perfectly in this form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="hidden-links">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content hidden-links">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times fa-fw fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
                <ul class="links-hidden" role="menu">
                <!--Hidden links here-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to move:

```
<div data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <i class="fa fa-times fa-fw fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```

out of the `.modal-body` so I can achieve something like this:

[image]

I've done some digging but I couldn't find a proper solution to my problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the markup slightly:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="hidden-links">
    <div data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <i class="fa fa-times fa-fw fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content hidden-links">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="links-hidden" role="menu">
                    <!--Hidden links here-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add come CSS:

```
div[data-dismiss="modal"]{
  color:#ffffff;
  position:fixed;
  top:10px;
  right:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

#### See it in action here